# Quick registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, refactoring

I'm trying to solve one problem, there are two applications: the first ASP.NET MVC and the second client-server application. After authorization in the ASP.NET MVC application, the user also accesses the client-server application. What is the best way to implement this function with cookies or using tokens? If there is a useful link, I will be grateful.

What is the best way to transfer data about an authorized user to a web application?

"Rough" mockup of what happened to me to implement. I provide it for an approximate representation of what I want to realize.

WebAppSetCookies:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModelUserInfo user)
{
   if(user != null)
   {
      UserInfo acc = new UserInfo() { Username = user.Name, Password = user.Password };

      var searching = userDb.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Username == acc.Username && 
                                                 f.Password == acc.Password);

       if(searching != null)
       {
           HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("user");
           cookie.Values["name"] = acc.Username;
           cookie.Values["password"] = acc.Password;

           Response.SetCookie(cookie);

           ViewBag.Authorization = "Successful!";

           return View(user);
       }
    }

    ViewBag.Authorization = "Wrong authorization!";

    return View();
}
```

WebAppGetCookies:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   UserInfo user;
   var cookie = Request.Cookies["user"];

   if (cookie != null)
   {
      user = new UserInfo() 
      { 
        Username = cookie.Values["name"], 
        Password = cookie.Values["password"] 
      };

      return View(user);
   }

   user = new UserInfo() { Username = "unknown", Password = "unknown" };

   return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only share HTTP cookies if both sites are a part of same root hostname, e.g. `some.site.com` and `another.site.on.site.com`. Such cookie would then have to be created with its domain part set to `site.com`. Only then browsers will send those cookies to both, regardless of which one included them. After that, the secondary target website will be able to work with them during their processing.

This would work if both sites are sharing more then just the root hostname; e.g. `site1.on.site.com` and `site2.on.site.com` would then both be able to work with `on.site.com` cookie.

Comment: but if I have different sites? How do I transfer user information (login and password) to the second site?

Comment: You don't [pass username and password around]. The topic I think you're interested in is called "single sign-on". You should google it, but here's one resource: http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc. The concept is that the user logs in once, and is then recognized at other websites in trusted realm. Google is doing this across all its websites, for example. This isn't something you can hope for a complete solution here. If you go through that tutorial, you should have understanding how this works at the end.

Comment: Many thanks for the article. but what if I have already implemented the registration and I have one application mvc, and the second is not mvc

Comment: It doesn't matter. The server-side concept is the same: all sites (including the site hosting the login page) share the same encryption key, which they use to decrypt information. Login-page site takes uid/pwd and creates either a cookie (if it can be shared, like I described previously) or a value to pass via query [to the other site]. Then, the target site (receiving cookie/query) can decrypt it, because it has the same key. The value that you encrypt is typically the username. This concept is based on trust between these sites. It doesn't matter what technology sites are using.

Comment: I just do not quite understand how the "angular" application will check the authorization of the user. It seems to be doing everything, as in the instructions, but there is no result

Comment: in principle, it is not clear how this works. by the instruction we are authorized in the SSO application (in my case it is an asp.net mvc application), then in the config we specify the machine key that will be unified for our applications. further in webapp1 we use this element in web.config (in my case it is an angular). But since the application uses its user verification tools, I do not understand how, in my case, the angular should access the web.config server

Comment: The encryption key and method defined within ASP.NET's web.config don't necessarily need to be used: you can use another. The overall picture of how SSO works is what the point here is: one site authenticates, then forwards the user to another site, while also passing encrypted information, which the receiving site will also be able to decrypt (because they share the key), where the transport of the encrypted value can be query, cookie or another back-end channel.

Comment: Can you suggest how you can configure authentication without resorting to SSO? In my case, it will take a lot of time, I would like to configure authentication by cookie or tokens?